# Show Duplicate Values in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called sales that has the fields 'sales_id', 'status' and 'product_id' I need a listing that shows me when a product_id appears twice only with different status = SENT and status = 'RECEIPT'.
Summarizing only shows the duplications when the product had with those two statuses in different sales id.

Comment: Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id
  FROM sales
 WHERE status IN ('SENT', 'RECEIPT')
 GROUP BY product_id
HAVING MIN(status) = 'RECEIPT' AND MAX(status) = 'SENT';
```

Comment: Oh well, maybe next time.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part of the code, now it worked perfectly, it only takes one last doubt. The two sales sales are on different dates I wanted him to show me the date that was received from the side too. Has as?

Comment: @BonfimJunior You want the date corresponding the `RECEIPT` status? Will that date always be the latest?

Comment: Yes, the received status date will always be recent than the sent date.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, status FROM sales
```

This will give you a row for each combination that exists of `product_id` and `status`.   Then you can summarize it like so:

```
SELECT product_id
  FROM (
             SELECT DISTINCT product_id, status FROM sales
       ) x
 GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

That will yield a list of `product_id` values with more than one status value.